# Prevent declaring variables without var

Tags: javascript, netbeans

How can I prevent variables from being declared without using the `var` keyword? Can I set NetBeans to warn me about this?

For example, I want a warning or something on this:

```
var testing = 5;

// ...

testin = 2; // Woops, typo!
```

Comment: Put `"use strict";` at the top of your code. It will force you to write clean code and declare your variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of at least a couple of possibilities for you. One is JSLint, as mentioned above. Another is to use the new Javascript feature called "strict mode" ([described here among other places](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/))

I have heard that the nightly builds of Firefox now support strict mode, as do the pre-release versions of Chrome. Soon all new browser versions will support it.

Comment: Yeah, if you use `foo = 'bar'` in strict mode, and `foo` isn't declared, it will throw an error.

Comment: @Nyuszika7H What kind of error exactly? An `alert("goto hell");`, or refreshing the page, or something?

Comment: @muntoo: Sorry, I don't know. Chrome's strict mode is not complete, they've only implemented some things.

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this question and thought it worth noting that ECMAScript 5 now has an option called "use strict".  Just put "use strict"; (including the quotes) on a line by itself either at the top of your script (to use it everywhere) or within a function to just use it in one spot.  See http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/ for more details.  Extremely handy!